# How to presskey editor action on Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

How do you press the Editor Action key on Android softkey using Espresso? I tried:

```
onView(withId(R.id.edToNumber)).perform(typeText("MDO158"),ViewActions.pressKey(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP), closeSoftKeyboard())
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To click the `ActionDone button` from the keyboard of a Specific EditText, you could done by using this code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.edToNumber)).perform(typeText("MDO158");
onView(withId(R.id.edToNumber)).perform(pressImeActionButton());
```

**Note:**

`pressImeActionButton()` not specifically used for click the `ActionDone button` from the keyboard, it click whatever `ActionButton` that the keyboard consist such as `ActionDone`, `ActionSearch`, `ActionNext`, etc.

**Optionally,** you can close the keyboard of a Specific EditText without click the ActionDone button by using this code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.edToNumber)).perform(typeText("MDO158");
onView(withId(R.id.edToNumber)).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code

```
onView(withId(R.id.edToNumber))
        .perform(typeText("some"), pressImeActionButton());
```